# Suggestion for the use of to_number in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

Below query is giving error.

```
select sob.set_of_books_id, orginfo.org_information1
from 
  gl_sets_of_books sob, 
  hr_organization_information orginfo
    where 
      sob.set_of_books_id = to_number(orginfo.org_information1);
```

[image]

The reason is `set_of_books_id` is number column and `org_information1` is varchar which is containing string and also numeric string. so it is type mismatch. we have to pick only those values which has numeric string in `org_information1`

to overcome this we used `regexp_like` which will pick only record which are numeric.

```
select sob.set_of_books_id, orginfo.org_information1
from  hr_organization_information orginfo, gl_sets_of_books sob
where sob.set_of_books_id = to_number(orginfo.org_information1)
and REGEXP_LIKE(orginfo.org_information1, '^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

We just added this line `and REGEXP_LIKE(orginfo.org_information1, '^[[:digit:]]+$');` in previous query and it is working properly.

My question is even in the last query, we are using where clause and joining same condition which was failing in first query .and `where` will definetly run before `AND`. so why it is not failing? will it fail for some records? or the query is proper?
is there any better way to use the second query.

if I am not using existing `where` condition then it is giving error. i dont know what is the issue with below query.

[image]

**We can not use `to_char` on `set_of_books_id` because that column contains index.and we cant modify to create func based index.We have to use index in our query**

Comment: _cant modify to create func based index_ - why can't you create a function-based index?

Comment: Hi Chris, Because table does not belongs to us. It is an EBS application in which one table is accessed by many application. They refused to create func based index. we are using their table for dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

> `where` will definitely run before `and`

No!

The optimizer is free to rearrange the conditions in your query. There's no guarantee it processes these top-to-bottom. This can lead to [surprising effects if the plan changes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrzAGLOcswo) (e.g. because you added/removes indexes).

Assuming you're on 12.2 or higher, instead of a regex you can use the `on conversion error` clause to map all the non-numeric values to `null`:

```
with rws as (
  select level x,
         case mod ( level, 3 )
           when 0 then chr ( level+64 )
           else to_char ( level )
         end y
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select y from rws
  where  x = to_number ( y default null on conversion error );
  
Y    
1     
2     
4     
5     
7     
8     
10
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I am using 11g. also i can not use to_char(sob.set_of_books_id) on this because this column contain index on underlying table. so we want to use index.  can we somehow modify above query and make it sure that it wont fail in any circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_CHAR` on the number column rather than `TO_NUMBER` on the string column:

```sql
select sob.set_of_books_id,
       orginfo.org_information1
from   hr_organization_information orginfo
       INNER JOIN gl_sets_of_books sob
       ON ( TO_CHAR(sob.set_of_books_id) = orginfo.org_information1 );
```

Or, from Oracle 12.2, you can use `TO_NUMBER(value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)`:

```sql
select sob.set_of_books_id,
       orginfo.org_information1
from   hr_organization_information orginfo
       INNER JOIN gl_sets_of_books sob
       ON ( sob.set_of_books_id
            = TO_NUMBER(orginfo.org_information1 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)
          );
```

Comment: We can not use to_char on set_of_books_id because that column contains index.and we cant modify to create func based index

Comment: _"We can not use to_char on set_of_books_id because that column contains index."_  The index does _not_ prevent you from using the function.  It simply means that if you use the function, the index cannot be used to help resolve the query, probably leading to a full table scan.  But this may not necessarily be a problem, either.  Have you actually _tired_ it?

Comment: Hi, Actually earlier condition was to_char(set_of_books_id)=org_information1 . perf team suggested us to change and use to_number so that index can be used. now index can be used but we are getting that conversion issue because org_information1 contains alphanumeric string as well. so converting them into number will throw error.